# Matchingproblems when using OpenCVs matchShapes function

Tags: opencv, pattern-matching, shapes, contour

I´m trying to find a objekt in a larger Picture with the findContour/matchShape functions (the object can vary so it´s not possible to look after the color or something similar, Featuredetectors like SIFT also doesn´t work because the object could be symetric)

[image]

I have written following code:

```
Mat scene = imread...
Mat Template = imread...
Mat imagegray1, imagegray2, imageresult1, imageresult2;
int thresh=80;
double ans=0, result=0;

// Preprocess pictures
cvtColor(scene, imagegray1,CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvtColor(Template,imagegray2,CV_BGR2GRAY);

GaussianBlur(imagegray1,imagegray1, Size(5,5),2);
GaussianBlur(imagegray2,imagegray2, Size(5,5),2);

Canny(imagegray1, imageresult1,thresh, thresh*2);
Canny(imagegray2, imageresult2,thresh, thresh*2);


vector<vector <Point> > contours1;
vector<vector <Point> >  contours2;
vector<Vec4i>hierarchy1, hierarchy2;
// Template
findContours(imageresult2,contours2,hierarchy2,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));
// Szene
findContours(imageresult1,contours1,hierarchy1,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));

imshow("template", Template);
double helper = INT_MAX;
int idx_i = 0, idx_j = 0;
// Match all contours with eachother
for(int i = 0; i < contours1.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < contours2.size(); j++)
    {
        ans=matchShapes(contours1[i],contours2[j],CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1 ,0);
        // find the best matching contour
        if((ans < helper) )
        {
            idx_i = i;
            helper =  ans;
        }
    }
}
  // draw the best contour 

 drawContours(scene, contours1, idx_i, 
 Scalar(255,255,0),3,8,hierarchy1,0,Point());
```

When I'm using a scene where only the Template is located in, i get a good matching result:
[image]

But when there are more objects in the pictures i have trouble detecting the object:
[image]

Hope someone can tell me whats the problem with the code i´m using. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a huge amount of contours in the second image (almost each letter).

[image: 2nd image with contours]

As the matchShape checks for scale-invariant Hu-moments (http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gab001db45c1f1af6cbdbe64df04c4e944) also a very small contours may fit the shape you are looking for.

Furthermore, the original shape is not distinguished properly like can be seen when excluding all contours with an area smaller 50.

```
if(contourArea(contours1[i]) > 50)
  drawContours(scene, contours1, i, Scalar(255, 255, 0), 1);
```

[image: 2nd image with contours larger 50]

To say it with other words, there is no problem with your code. The contour can simply not be detected very well. I would suggest to have a look at `approxCurve` and `convexHull` and try to close the contour this way. Or improve the use of `Canny` in some way.

Then you could use a priori knowledge to restrict the size (and maybe rotation?) of the contour you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation on what went "wrong".  I´m currently trying to follow your suggestions